# Getting "failed to ping registry" when trying hello-world on new instance

Tags: concourse

So, I'm testing a new instance of concourse on a private network that has a secured Docker registry.  From the host perspective, everything works fine.  I made sure that "docker login" was run and I can pull an image.  However, when I run the hello-world job, it fails with the following error:

```
failed to ping registry: 2 error(s) occurred.
```

Below that it lists two URLs for the registry: one http and one https with the following at the end of each:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

So, my question is, why is this occurring?  Is docker being called from within a container and therefore not able to access the /root/.docker/config.json file that has the login info?  Is there something else that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either specify specific trusted certs using the `ca-certs` option in https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource, or you can override this by specifying the hosts you want to access using `insecure-registries`

Comment: Yep.  That was it.  I added the email, insecure_registry, password, and username options to the image_resource.source section and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326209/cant-get-concourse-to-accept-self-signed-certs-when-looking-up-docker-images?noredirect=1#comment77615176_45326209 Can you update your question with the correct syntax?