# can't get concourse to accept self signed certs when looking up Docker images

Tags: concourse

I'm trying to get the helloworld sample to run. Problem is my company using a MITM proxy that replaces all certs on https connections with its own. So all tools that try to go to an https url fail.

In this case it is the code that downloads a Docker image from the official registry:

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1

stderr:
failed to ping registry: 2 error(s) occurred:

* ping https: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
* ping http: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried to add the `insecure_registries` option but that doesn't seem to work:

```
jobs:
- name: hello-world
plan:
- task: say-hello
  config:
    platform: linux
    image_resource:
      type: docker-image
      source: 
        repository: ubuntu,
        insecure_registries: ["docker.io:80"]

    run:
      path: echo
      args: ["Hello, world!"]
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: How about instead of `docker.io` use `registry-1.docker.io`

Comment: thanks but  I tried that already, was my first attempt

Comment: How is concourse ci setup in your case?

Comment: I followed the vagrant tutorial from the site: https://concourse.ci/vagrant.html

Comment: Is this still broken if you remove the comma after `repository: ubuntu`?

Comment: yes, removing the comma didn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem a number of users have encountered and one we are trying to find a general solution to that we can use for all resources. If you are interested in our progress on that, you can read more on [this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1027)

In the meantime, you can try using the `ca_certs` option to pass your man in the middle proxy's certificates into the resource. Note that `ca_certs` can not be used in combination with `insecure_registries`. Without seeing your exact configuration I can't give an exact solution but if `ca_certs` does not solve your issue, you should also look into the `client_certs` flag.

You can read more about all of these options in the `docker-image-resource` documentation [here.](https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource)

Comment: Unfortunately ca_certs seems broken atm, I run into this: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1340. I'm using 3.2.1 now, the version I got when following the vagrant setup.